# How does a method of moments estimate compare with a true value of the parameter?

Tags: self-study, mean, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-function, method-of-moments

To cut the long story short, I've been given this information:
pdf:$$f_X=\tau xexp\left({\frac{-\tau x^2}{2}}\right)$$
$x,\tau>0$ I went ahead and found the cdf:$$F(X)=1-exp\left(\frac{-\tau x^2}{2}\right)$$
And $E(X):$
$$E(X)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\pi}{2\tau}\right)}$$
and asked to find a method of moments estimate which I found out to be:
$$\hat{\tau}=\frac{\pi}{2\bar{x}^2}$$
Then I've been given a sample of 50 results taken from $F(X)$ with $\tau=0.2$. I found the mean of the sample to be $2.74355$. I substituted the sample mean to the method of moments estimate to find 
$$\hat{r}=0.20869$$

The question i am struggling to answer is how this estmiated $\tau$ compares with a real value of tau. I believe there probably is a test to see the comparison, because well, whenever you are asked to compare somthing in Stats there is a test to it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1. Although you make it clear that this is homework / self-study, still best to add the self-study tag, just for clarity for people who look at tags.  2. Although your deduction is a good one, depending on the level of the class and what you've learned already you may not actually be being asked for a test.  Have you learned about bootstrapping yet?

Comment: @jbowman yes, this is part of the bootstraping question, however it's the next part that asks to write the bootstrap algorithm to find uncertainty, and that part will require 500 samples.  This part of the question only asks "How does estimated parameter compares with the true value $\tau=0.2$

Comment: In that case, I'm guessing that a qualitative response is all that's needed.  You should check with the instructor, though.